# Get Azure VM details by filtering using tags in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, tags

I will like to use the `Get-AzVm` command to get list of VMs having a specific tag.

I have tried `Get-AzVM | Where-Object {$_.Tags['Resource'] -eq "test"}`

Still does not return VMS with the tag "Resource:test"

Answer (score 0):

The output of `get-azvm` doesn't produce Tags for VM. But, `Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -Name VMName` does that.

So you need to loop through VMs, store the VM tag in a hashtable and then enumerate through the hastable to check your desired tag with value is there. Here goes the code-

```
$VMs = get-azvm
foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    [Hashtable]$VMTag = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name  $VM.Name).Tags
    foreach ($h in $VMTag.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (($h.Name -eq "Resource") -and ($h.value -eq "test"))
        {
            Write-host "VM with tags Resource:test are" $VM.Name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to use 

`$VMs = Get-AzVM`
`Write-host "VM with tags 'Resource:Test':"`
`foreach ($Vm in $VMs)`
`{`
   ` if (($Vm.Tags.keys -eq 'Resource') -and ($Vm.Tags.values -eq 'Test'))`
   ` { `
        `Write-Host $Vm.Name`
   ` } `
`}`

However it seems not to work for some tags

Comment: You have to update the condition `(($h.Name -eq "Resource") -and ($h.value -eq "test"))` based on your tag and value. If the answer is helpful do mark it